# Unable to locate package gcc-defaults error

Tags: package-management

This is the command I use:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gcc-defaults
```

When I run it, the terminal shows the error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-defaults
```

Why? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a source package. To obtain it, do

```
sudo apt-get source gcc-defaults
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

update your apt-get firstly.